# Set 'src' attribute for document.createElement('script')?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create a highchart on a different tab. But Im getting error that high chart is not defined. I have tried to register Highchart.js using different methods. Code is given below.

```
function OpenWin() {   
  var w = window.open();
  w.document.open();
  w.document.write('<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>');

  var scriptHead = w.document.createElement("SCRIPT");
  //scriptHead.setAttribute('src','http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js');
  var link = "http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js";
  scriptHead.src = link;
  w.document.head.appendChild(scriptHead);

  var script = w.document.createElement("SCRIPT");
  w.document.body.appendChild(script);
  var js = w.document.createTextNode('var a = localStorage.getItem("ImportOptions"); console.log(JSON.parse(a)); var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(JSON.parse(a))');
  script.appendChild(js);
  w.document.close();    
}
```

Comment: You should probably use the script load event to define logic using it. I guess the way you are adding it, `scriptHead` is async. So try to set following logic in `scriptHead.onload = function(){var script = w.document.createElement("SCRIPT"); /*...*/};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wait for previous script to load. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ohr5eLvw/).

```
function OpenWin() {   
  var w = window.open();
  w.document.open();
  w.document.write('<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>');

  var scriptHead = w.document.createElement("SCRIPT");
  //scriptHead.setAttribute('src','http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js');
  var link = "http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js";

  // bind on script load event
  scriptHead.onload = function() {
      var script = w.document.createElement("SCRIPT");
      w.document.body.appendChild(script);
      var js = w.document.createTextNode('var a = localStorage.getItem("ImportOptions"); console.log(JSON.parse(a)); var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(JSON.parse(a))');
      script.appendChild(js);
      w.document.close();        
  }

  // as A.Wolff mentioned you might need to set onload befor src for some browsers.
  scriptHead.src = link;
  w.document.head.appendChild(scriptHead);
}
```

Comment: Ya but i'd set `scriptHead.src` after define `scriptHead.onload`. If i'm correct, on some (older?) browsers, if script cached, load event won't be fired otherwise.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko This Worked. Thanks alot :D